# colorschemes are messed up in vim (mac OSX, iTerm2, zsh, vim 7.2 and 7.3)

Tags: vim, terminal, colors, zsh

For some reason in vim my colors come out looking weird. There are a few colorschemes that look correct like solarize and one called BusyBee but I'm not sure why most of my other color schemes come out looking very strange. It looks like there aren't enough colors being displayed. I know that the colorscheme is wrong because I have MacVim installed so I know how the colors are supposed to look. I've even installed Xcode because I saw that as a solution somewhere.

I'm using iTerm2 so I know it supports 256 colors. I set the terminal type to xterm-256. I have syntax highlighting on in vim. I even tried upgrading to vim 7.3 but I still have the same problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I've been searching around for answers to this literally ALL DAY long. Only to realize that it appears I am trying to use 2^32 colors which are for graphical vim apps. It looks like all the 256 color schemes I try are working fine. ARGGG!!!@#$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 256-color schemes or try [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390). I don't use it myself but it gets recommended a lot on IRC.

> This plugin makes GVim-only
>   colorschemes Just Work in terminal
>   Vim, as long as the terminal supports
>   88 or 256 colors